# Some User-scoped My.Settings string propeties are blank upon startup

Tags: vb.net, my.settings

VB.Net, WindowsForm:  I have six user-scoped strings configured in the project Settings tab.  If I do a Debug.WriteLine for these immediately in the Form Load event of the project's startup form, some strings print correctly, but others print as "".

If I change the name of one of the ones that print "", then the first time I run the application, the correct value prints.  After that it goes back to printing "".  If I change the name again to another name that has already been used, "" still prints.

If I create a new application, any settings strings are always available upon startup.  Since I have the Debug.WriteLine statement immediately at the start of my problem application, I don't see where the problem might be.

Comment: You'll actually have two sets of values, one for the DEBUG version, and one for the RELEASE version.  It's possible this is coming into play?...

Comment: Yes, this is probably what I was missing.  Things seem OK now.  Thanks.